# Set HH:MM:SS to zero with swift

Tags: swift, date, datetime

How can i go about setting the HH:MM:SS all to show zeros.

```
let date: NSDate = NSDate()
println(date)
//this is how the output looks like now 2015-07-11 14:57:35 +0000
```

I've tried to use NSDateFormatter and set the style without HH:MM:SS, it does not work either. tried the calendar function too

the output i am looking for is

```
2015-07-11 00:00:00 +0000
```

what i am trying to do is to query for a specific date and time based on the range of 2 days, which is before and after the specified date